# OVH Domain & Let's encrypt SSL failure

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, ovh

I'm trying to install Let's Encrypt Cert on OVH Hosting but I can't enable SSL in Multisite options.

First, I go to Multisite options in order to do that.

I've got all SSL turned off there. I choose edit, then check the SSL box, then next and finally Confirm button. And then I get the error.

I searched for the solution but I've found none for this one. Am I doing something wrong?

When I try to activate the SSL in the options for the domain (after clicking on the Confirm button) I get the error message which says *an error has occured when modifying the domain/s of your hosting plan*.

[An image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O0MZ.png)
[Error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WT0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Funny how people give minuses but they can't answer the question. This proves asking questions here is useless anyway.

Btb, I found it. For those who might find it useful in the future: check all the records in the DNS Zone.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but I don't understand your solution. What do you mean with "check all the records in the DNS Zone" ? What to check?

Comment: @neiya It may turn out that there are some (specifically A) records that just don't direct it properly to your hosting server. The problem I had stemmed from the fact somebody else had modified the records in the past and nobody knew what was going on. It turned out the record for the hosting on OVH was incorrectly put. 

So first you just need to go to the DNS area on your OVH and check all the A records (or AAAA if this is about IPv6) if they match what they should match.

Comment: Thanks! The DNS records or the problematic domain point to cluster 15, but the hosting plan associated with this domain is cluster 21. I think this is because I have two domains, but my personal plan is the one related to cluster 15. So everything is stored there. For my second domain, I don't have a real hosting plan. Does that prevent me to enable HTTPS on the second domain?